# Angularjs & Google Analytics Integration

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

I'm using AngularJS UI Router, and revolunet/angular-google-analytics
https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics

Here it is my config:

```
.config(function(AnalyticsProvider) {
        // initial configuration
        AnalyticsProvider.setAccount('UA-XXXXXXX-X');

        // track all routes/states (or not)
        AnalyticsProvider.trackPages(true);

        // Use analytics.js instead of ga.js
        AnalyticsProvider.useAnalytics(true);

        // change page event name
        AnalyticsProvider.setPageEvent('$stateChangeSuccess');
}))
```

Now is there any other steps to complete? I have NOT modified any states/controllers to include any analytics code, is there anything else required? And what does the following comment means? I guess enabling 'trackPages' is enough, am I right?

```
.run(function(Analytics) {
  // In case you are relying on automatic page tracking, you need to inject Analytics
  // at least once in your application (for example in the main run() block)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official reply from @revolunet 
https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics/issues/35

> You can check if it works in the chrome network console. check calls
>   to google. (via an image i guess)
>
> About the Analytics you need to inject it manually at least once
>   somewhere in your app. (the run block is the good place) so it can be
>   instantiated by angular.